# Python Tkinter place_forget() method to update program

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I've built a finance calculator using Tkinter, utilised the place method. All the functions work however it needs to work like the following:

When the investment is clicked the investments (simple or compound) are shown along with the word Interest Earned. Otherwise if bond is selected it will not display that.

Currently everything works except just one thing.

The amount will not disappear if i clicked simple AND compound or vice versa , also if I click bond twice. If I select either interest once and then click bond everything disappears correctly , if I select bond and then interest once more it works but as soon as I try to do simple and compound in one calculation that amount will not go away also if I select bond and do calculations on it again that amount will not go away.

This is the last step to complete the app help would really be appreciated.

```
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *


# this is a function to remove or add an element to the window
def removeInvestments():

  invest_label.place_forget()
  interest_earned_label.place_forget()
  typeOfInvestment.place_forget()
  text.place_forget()


def removeBonds():
  monthly_payment.place_forget()
  amount_text_bond.place_forget()


# this is a function to get the selected list box value
def getTypeOfCalc(*args):

  itemSelected = typeOfCalculator.curselection()
  # print(itemSelected)

  for item in itemSelected:

      if item == 0:
          typeOfInvestment.place(x=315, y=102)
          interest_earned_label.place(x=25, y=468)
          invest_label.place(x=314, y=69)
          removeBonds()

      elif item == 1:
          monthly_payment.place(x=24, y=382)
          amount_text_bond.place(x=400, y=382)
          removeInvestments()

  return itemSelected


# this is a function to get the user input from the text input box
def getAmount():
  userInput = amount.get()
  userInputFloat = float(userInput)
  return userInputFloat


# this is a function to get the user input from the text input box
def getDuration():
  userInput = duration.get()
  userInputFloat = float(userInput)
  return userInputFloat


# this is a function to get the user input from the text input box
def getInterest():
  userInput = interest_rate.get()
  userInputFloat = float(userInput)
  return userInputFloat


# this is a function to get the selected list box value
def getInvestmentType():
  itemSelected = typeOfInvestment.curselection()
  return itemSelected

# this is the function called when the button is clicked


def btnClickFunction():

  if getTypeOfCalc() == (0,):
      investmentCalc()

  elif getTypeOfCalc() == (1,):
      bondCalc()


def investmentCalc():
  global text

  amount = getAmount()
  duration = getDuration()
  interest = getInterest()
  type_invest = getInvestmentType()
  #calc = getTypeOfCalc()

  if type_invest == (0,):

      s_interest = (amount * duration * interest)/100
      text = Label(root, text=f'R{s_interest}', bg='#F0F8FF', font=(
          'arial', 30, 'normal'))
      text.place(x=320, y=468)

  elif type_invest == (1,):

      c_interest = amount * (pow((1 + interest / 100), duration))
      c_interest = round(c_interest, 2)
      text = Label(root, text=f'R{c_interest}', bg='#F0F8FF', font=(
          'arial', 30, 'normal'))
      text.place(x=320, y=468)

  # To test it is taking user input
  #print(amount, duration, interest, type_invest, calc)


def bondCalc():
  global amount_text_bond

  amount = getAmount()
  duration = getDuration()
  interest = getInterest()

  monthly_repayment = interest * amount / \
      (1 - pow((1 + interest), - duration))
  monthly_repayment = round(monthly_repayment, 2)

  amount_text_bond = Label(root, text=f'R{monthly_repayment}', bg='#F0F8FF',
                           font=('arial', 30, 'normal'))
  amount_text_bond.place(x=400, y=382)

  # print(monthly_repayment)


root = Tk()


# This is the section of code which creates the main window
root.geometry('893x596')
root.configure(background='#F0F8FF')
root.title('Finance Calculator')


# This is the section of code which creates the a label
Label(root, text='Welcome To The Finance Calculator',
    bg='#F0F8FF', font=('arial', 30, 'normal')).place(x=123, y=4)


# This is the section of code which creates the a label
Label(root, text='Type Of Calculator', bg='#F0F8FF',
    font=('arial', 15, 'normal')).place(x=27, y=72)


# This is the section of code which creates a listbox
typeOfCalculator = Listbox(root, exportselection=0, bg='#F0F8FF', font=(
  'arial', 15, 'normal'), width=0, height=0)
typeOfCalculator.insert('0', 'Investment Calculator')
typeOfCalculator.insert('1', 'Bond Calculator')
typeOfCalculator.place(x=28, y=104)


# This is the section of code which creates the a label
Label(root, text='Amount', bg='#F0F8FF', font=(
  'arial', 15, 'normal')).place(x=28, y=185)


# This is the section of code which creates a text input box
amount = Entry(root)
amount.place(x=114, y=187)


# This is the section of code which creates the a label
Label(root, text='Duration', bg='#F0F8FF', font=(
  'arial', 15, 'normal')).place(x=26, y=239)


# This is the section of code which creates a text input box
duration = Entry(root)
duration.place(x=113, y=240)


# This is the section of code which creates the a label
Label(root, text='Interest', bg='#F0F8FF', font=(
  'arial', 15, 'normal')).place(x=28, y=286)


# This is the section of code which creates a text input box
interest_rate = Entry(root)
interest_rate.place(x=113, y=288)

# This is the section of code which creates a button
Button(root, text='Calculate', bg='#F0F8FF', font=('arial', 12,
                                                 'normal'), command=btnClickFunction).place(x=291, y=270)


# First, we create a canvas to put the picture on
worthAThousandWords = Canvas(root, height=200, width=200)
# Then, we actually create the image file to use (it has to be a *.gif)
# <-- you will have to copy-paste the filepath here, for example 'C:\Desktop\pic.gif'
picture_file = PhotoImage(file='./logo_.gif')
# Finally, we create the image on the canvas and then place it onto the main window
worthAThousandWords.create_image(200, 0, anchor=NE, image=picture_file)
worthAThousandWords.place(x=660, y=105)


# This is the section of code which creates the a label
invest_label = Label(root, text='Type Of Investment', bg='#F0F8FF',
                   font=('arial', 15, 'normal'))


# This is the section of code which creates a listbox
# Setting exportselection to 0 ensures multiple listboxes in one window can be selected
typeOfInvestment = Listbox(root, exportselection=0, bg='#F0F8FF', font=(
  'arial', 15, 'normal'), width=0, height=0)
typeOfInvestment.insert('0', 'Simple Interest')
typeOfInvestment.insert('1', 'Compound Interest')


# This is the section of code which creates the a label
monthly_payment = Label(root, text='Monthly Repayment', bg='#F0F8FF',
                      font=('arial', 30, 'normal'))


# This is the section of code which creates the a label
interest_earned_label = Label(root, text='Interest Earned', bg='#F0F8FF',
                            font=('arial', 30, 'normal'))

amount_text_bond = Label(root, text=f'', bg='#F0F8FF',
                       font=('arial', 30, 'normal'))

text = Label(root, text=f'', bg='#F0F8FF', font=(
  'arial', 30, 'normal'))


# Keep changing the selected item in the listbox
typeOfCalculator.bind('<Double-1>', getTypeOfCalc)


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem in your code except for the fact that you are recreating the label again and again instead of using the existing label. All you have to change is `amount_text_bond = Label(root, text=f'R{monthly_repayment}', bg='#F0F8FF',font=('arial', 30, 'normal'))` in `bondCalc` to `amount_text_bond.config(text = f'R{monthly_repayment}')`

```
def bondCalc():

  amount = getAmount()
  duration = getDuration()
  interest = getInterest()

  monthly_repayment = interest * amount / \
      (1 - pow((1 + interest), - duration))
  monthly_repayment = round(monthly_repayment, 2)

  amount_text_bond.config(text = f'R{monthly_repayment}')
  amount_text_bond.place(x=400, y=382)
```

similarly:

```
def investmentCalc():
  global text

  amount = getAmount()
  duration = getDuration()
  interest = getInterest()
  type_invest = getInvestmentType()
  #calc = getTypeOfCalc()

  if type_invest == (0,):

      s_interest = (amount * duration * interest)/100
      text.config(text=f'R{s_interest}')

  elif type_invest == (1,):

      c_interest = amount * (pow((1 + interest / 100), duration))
      c_interest = round(c_interest, 2)
      text.config(text=f'R{c_interest}')
      
  text.place(x=320, y=468)
```

you can simply replace your functions I rewrote.

also if you have a problem displaying image use this instead `picture_file = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(r'\yourImage'))`